# delete array using the indices in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have an array in this form

```
 arr=   [
        [0.11, 2.6875],
        [0.11, 2.6875],
        [100, 200],
        [100, 200],
        [100, 200],
        [0.0033, 4.66677],
        [300, 400],
        [300, 400],
        [300, 400]
    ]
```

I am using list.remove() function but it is not working as expected.

The below array consists if list of tuples which has index number and its element. I need to delete those elements from the original array by taking the below array as reference

```
[(1, [0.11, 2.6875]), (2, [100, 200]), (3, [100, 200]), (4, [100, 200]), (7, [300, 400]), (8, [300, 400])]
```

Desired output:

```
 res=   [[0.11, 2.6875],[0.0033, 4.66677],[300, 400]]
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @MattDMo used .remove() and .pop(). the array is restructuring

Comment: Try iterating over it in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
arr=   [
 [0.11, 2.6875],
 [0.11, 2.6875],
 [100, 200],
 [100, 200],
 [100, 200],
 [0.0033, 4.66677],
 [300, 400],
 [300, 400],
 [300, 400]
]

removals = [(1, [0.11, 2.6875]), (2, [100, 200]), (3, [100, 200]), (4, [100, 200]), (7, [300, 400]), (8, [300, 400])]

for item in removals:
    arr.remove(item[1])

print(arr)

# [[0.11, 2.6875], [0.0033, 4.66677], [300, 400]]
```